# Combination search for character vector

Tags: r, pattern-matching, character, combinations, permutation

```
a<-c('a','b','c','d')
```

Need this to be segregated in combinations

Required output is

```
(a b c d,a b c,b c d,a b,b c,c d,a,b,c,d)
```

Comment: What is the logic behind your output? How is it selected?

Comment: quite sure this is a dupe: `unlist(lapply(seq_along(a), function(m) combn(a, m, simplify=FALSE)), recursive=FALSE)`

Comment: But ill be getting this in list format @chinsoon12 
need that in character format back with spaces like (a b),(a c c)

Comment: lapply(prevoutput, paste, collapse=“ “)

Comment: Unable to get the output..
I meant i have 1 character vector and 1 data frame as inputs and have search each keyword from the character vector into particular column  if matched I store the matched words.
a <- c('a,a b,a b c,a b c d') AND df <- data.frame(rbind(c('a',1,'ewew'),c('a b c',101,'dffdhsd'),c('d f',405,'rtrtrtr')))
Desire Output should in this case will be both words in first column
a, a b c

Answer (score 1):

I used @chinsoon12 suggestions with a further `paste` to get your required output:

```
paste(lapply(unlist(lapply(rev(seq_along(a)), function(m) combn(a, m, simplify=FALSE)), recursive=FALSE), paste, collapse=" "), collapse=",")
```

Returns:
"a b c d,a b c,a b d,a c d,b c d,a b,a c,a d,b c,b d,c d,a,b,c,d"

Comment: What if we have a space as input like 
a<-c('a b c d') this can be segregated 
(a b c d,a b c,b c d,a b,b c,c d,a,b,c,d)

Comment: @SarathChandra you can use `str_split` from the `stringr` package to convert an input with spaces to the same format. i.e. `a <- unlist(str_split(a, " "))`

Comment: Thanks alot @drjones One last doubt
Is there a chance that i can get only (a,a b,a b c,a b c d)) instead of all probabilities.

Comment: @SarathChandra this will give you the required output: `paste(lapply(1:length(a),FUN=function(x) paste(a[1:x],collapse=" ")),collapse=",")`

Comment: Can i use this output like (a,a b,a b c,a b c d)) 
Like first word of character ie just "a" grep(search function) to another dataframe ie df<-data.frame(rbind(c('a',1,'ewew'),c('a b c',101,'dffdhsd')))

Answer (score 0):

The desired output can be built from the [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of `c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd') = letters[1:4]`. Using the `powerset` function from the `rje` library, we have:

```
unlist(lapply(rje::powerSet(letters[1:4])[-1], paste0, collapse = ' '))
[1] "a"       "b"       "a b"     "c"       "a c"     "b c"     "a b c"  
[8] "d"       "a d"     "b d"     "a b d"   "c d"     "a c d"   "b c d"  
[15] "a b c d"
```

Comment: Can i use this output like (a,a b,a b c,a b c d)) Like first word of character ie just "a" grep(search function) to another dataframe ie df<-data.frame(rbind(c('a',1,'ewew'),c('a b c',101,'dffdhsd')))

Comment: @SarathChandra , I’m not really sure what you are asking. If this doesn’t solve your problem, edit your question or ask another question with your desired output.

Comment: Unable to get the output..
I meant i have 1 character vector and 1 data frame as inputs and have search each keyword from the character vector into particular column  if matched I store the matched words.
a <- c('a,a b,a b c,a b c d') AND df <- data.frame(rbind(c('a',1,'ewew'),c('a b c',101,'dffdhsd'),c('d f',405,'rtrtrtr')))
Desire Output should in this case will be both words in first column
a, a b c